# What is the difference between interpreter and mediator design pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interpreter, mediator

I am reading design pattern and going through the concept of all that.

Facing some issue while reading the concept of the mediator and interpreter pattern...Can any body please help me to get clear about this

By example and explanation which I got from internet it is stating that..

**Interpreter**
A way to include language elements in a program

**Mediator**
Defines simplified communication between classes

But when we think about the Interpreter it also looks doing same thing as mediator...as in interpreter the middle interface is required that can convert the language elements(seen in example of Roman to normal number conversion from [interpreter example](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/interpreter/cpp/1)) also mediator concept provides middle interface that can communicate with other interfaces.

Can anyone give generic example that can clarify the clear difference between Mediator and Interpreter pattern.

Please give example in c++ as I am not aware of java concepts.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Java, if the question doesn't have to do with Java and you don't want the answer in Java?

Comment: because some of java candidate will have good examples that also knows c++ funda @yshavit

Comment: Please do not spam the tags. If you want a question in c++ and not Java, then don't tag Java just in the hope that someone who watches that tag also knows c++. Those people probably watch both tags, anyway.

Comment: As far as I know so many persons who know java, will  also be better in c++ concepts. I can find many good examples in other design patterns in <java> not in <C++>.....so please if you don't  know the answer of my question leave the  topic of this. thanks for it. @yshavit

Comment: The mystery here is what you think these two patterns have in common. Apart from the presence of a middle interface, which is common to many design patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Interpreter](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Interpreter/) pattern is used to interpreter a (domain) language defined with grammatical rules.
[Mediator](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Mediator/) is used when it is hard to achieve synchronization among the lot of objects, then communication goes via mediator.

Hope that this helps.